# Logstash aggregate filter didnt add new field into index in-fact didn't created any index after aggregation filter add

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, aggregate, kibana

Dears,

i have created two grok pattern for in single log file , i want add existing field to another document if condition match , could you advice  me how to add one existing field to another document
my log input

my input

```
INFO  [2020-05-21 18:00:17,240][appListenerContainer-3][ID:b5ba824c-9f79-4dd4-9d53-1012250ce72a] - ValidationRuleSegmentStops - CarrierCode = AI ServiceNumber = 0531 DeparturePortCode = DEL ArrivalPortCode = CCJ DepartureDateTime = Thu May 21 XXXXX AST 2020 ArrivalDateTime = Thu May 21 XXX
WARN  [2020-05-21 18:00:17,242][appListenerContainer-3][ID:b5ba824c-9f79-4dd4-9d53-1012250ce72a] - ValidationRuleSegmentStops - Multiple segment stops with departure datetime not set - only one permitted. Message sequence number 374991954 discarded
INFO  [2020-05-21 18:00:17,242][appListenerContainer-3][ID:b5ba824c-9f79-4dd4-9d53-1012250ce72a] - SensitiveDataFilterHelper - Sensitive Data Filter key is not enabled.
ERROR [2020-05-21 18:00:17,243][appListenerContainer-3][ID:b5ba824c-9f79-4dd4-9d53-1012250ce72a] - AbstractMessageHandler - APP_LOGICAL_VALIDATION_FAILURE: comment1 = Multiple segment stops with departure datetime not set - only one permitted. Message sequence number 374991954 discarded
```

my filter

```
filter {

if [type] == "server"  {
    grok {
     match => [ "message", "%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}\s+\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:createddatetime}\]\[%{DATA:lstcontainer}\](?<seg_corid>[^\s]+)\s+\-\s+%{WORD:abstract}\s+\-\s+CarrierCode\s+=\s+(?<carrierCode>[A-Z0-9]{2})\s+ServiceNumber\s+=\s+(?<Number>[0-9]{4})\s+DeparturePortCode\s+=\s+(?<DeparturePort>[A-Z]{3})\s+ArrivalPortCode\s+=\s+(?<ArrivalPort>[A-Z]{3})\s+DepartureDateTime\s+=\s+%{DATESTAMP_OTHER:departure_datetime}\s+ArrivalDateTime\s+=\s+%{DATESTAMP_OTHER:arrival_datetime},%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}\s+\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:createddatetime}\]\[%{DATA:lstcontainer}\](?<failed_corid>[^\s]+)\s+\-\s+%{WORD:abstract}\s+\-\s+(?<app-logical-error>[A-Z]{3}\_[A-Z]{7}\_[A-Z]{10}\_[A-Z]{7})\:\s+comment1 = Multiple segment stops with\s+%{WORD:direction}\s+datetime not set - only one permitted. Message sequence number\s+%{NUMBER:appmessageid:int}"]

}

}

if [failed_corid] == "%{seg_corid}" {
aggregate {
task_id => "%{appmessageid}"
code => "map['carrierCode'] = [carrierCode]"
map_action => "create"
end_of_task => true
timeout => 120
}
}

mutate { remove_field => ["message"]}

if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags]{drop {} }

}

output {
 if [type] == "server" {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["X.X.X.X:9200"]
    index => "app-data-%{+YYYY-MM-DD}"
  }
}
}
my requred fields found in defferent grok patter for example
```

carrier code found in

```
%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}\s+\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:createddatetime}\]\[%{DATA:lstcontainer}\](?<seg_corid>[^\s]+)\s+\-\s+%{WORD:abstract}\s+\-\s+CarrierCode\s+=\s+(?<carrierCode>[A-Z0-9]{2})\s+ServiceNumber\s+=\s+(?<Number>[0-9]{4})\s+DeparturePortCode\s+=\s+(?<DeparturePort>[A-Z]{3})\s+ArrivalPortCode\s+=\s+(?<ArrivalPort>[A-Z]{3})\s+DepartureDateTime\s+=\s+%{DATESTAMP_OTHER:departure_datetime}\s+ArrivalDateTime\s+=\s+%{DATESTAMP_OTHER:arrival_datetime},
```

and failed corid found in

```
%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}\s+\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:createddatetime}\]\[%{DATA:lstcontainer}\](?<failed_corid>[^\s]+)\s+\-\s+%{WORD:abstract}\s+\-\s+(?<app-logical-error>[A-Z]{3}\_[A-Z]{7}\_[A-Z]{10}\_[A-Z]{7})\:\s+comment1 = Multiple segment stops with\s+%{WORD:direction}\s+datetime not set - only one permitted. Message sequence number\s+%{NUMBER:appmessageid:int}
```

we want to merge carriercode field into failed_corid documents

kindly help us how to do it in logstash

expected output fields in the documents

```
 {
         "failed_corid": [id-433erfdtert3er]
         "carrier_code": AI 

         }
```

Comment: aggregate filter didn't worked   , is it possible to map  fields from different grok pattern ?
for example i have two pattern from single log file , in the second document i want some fields that exists in the first pattern  , how can i achieve that  ?

Comment: Are you running your pipeline with only one worker? The aggregate filter needs that. Also, update your question and share your example input data, what you want to do and the expected output.

Comment: Hi @leandrojmp  i have updated the question , kindly need you advise  on this

Comment: None of your example messages are matching your grok pattern, and since you are dropping messages with the tag `_grokparsefailure`, all these messages would be dropped. You need first to fix your grok to make it match the messages you want, you have different types of messages. Also, what is setting the field `type` as `riskserver`? You didn't share your input or how you are ingesting your data. And are you using only one worker on your pipeline?

Comment: hi @leandrojmp ,  the grok pattern is matching ( some log comments are masked in the input log ,  is it possible to merge two grok patterns into single document if condition matched ?  we really need your help

Comment: @leandrojmp yes   we are using  oner worker for our pipelines

Comment: I tried your messages in grok debugger and none of them matched the grok in your pipeline. Looking closer into them, I see that the message where you have the carrier code does not seem to have the field you are using to aggregate, the message sequence number. To aggregate two or more messages you need a common field present in all of them.